# How to get around connecting to a party that has already been connected

Tags: c, sockets, asynchronous, networking, connection

I am facing difficulties to determine how to de-sync connections from two parties according to my program architecture. It is a P2P chat. Each party is connecting to one another automatically as the program starts. The connecting process is asynchronous.
When there is incoming connection, a signal is invoked from the listener and the signal handler takes care of the connection. So the "accept" is also asynchronous.

This will ultimately connect both users twice. There will be two connections.
Both sides will be server and client. And this is unwanted.
Now I tried quite a few things to solve this, but none really worked.
For instance, I checked in the listener signal handler if socket on that IP already exists and if so disconnect it and return. But the connection is designed in such a way that the other side will keep trying to connect.

What is the correct approach to design it and what are the alternatives?

Comment: Ignore the incoming requests before the start-up is not completed.

Comment: @P__J__ In that case no one will be connected.

Comment: @P__J__ That would mean the other side will also ignore incoming requests before startup and as a result, no connection will be accepted. It is a P2P chat, same program for every peer.

Comment: This is the unique pairs problem. (If you have N peers, there are N*(N-1)/2 unique pairs. If each of them connects to every other, you have N*(N-1) connections.) You need to order all peers somehow -- based on IP address and port, maybe? --, and have each peer `connect()` to peers ordered before themselves, and `accept()` connections from peers ordered later than themselves.

Comment: Another option is to make all connections, in which you have each connection twice. The endpoints of each can be obtained via [`getsockname()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsockname.2.html) and [`getpeername()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpeername.2.html); these will be mirrored on the other end. Have the peers agree which one of the duplicate connections is dropped based on the socket addresses.

Comment: @NominalAnimal What you have said about ordering sounds pretty much like a valid solution. And you described the problem. It is a bit confusing to understand it fully. You can make it an answer if you like, with some illustration that will help imagining and understanding it.
Once a connection is established a receiving thread is started and what not so it is not a good idea to allow duplicated connections on a first place.

Comment: Generally this opens the gates for problems. I don't see any remotely related problem, but I can notice that the peers become functional after both connections are established only and this takes a lot of time. When I connect them manually, the connection is instant. Also I am using a high level API with GSocket-based interface. But the underlying socket type is windows SOCKET, so no restrictions whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at a situation with four peers:

[image: Four peers]
If every peer connects to every other peer, there will be two connections between each pair of peers. (If there are N peers, there are N(N-1)/2 unique pairs.)

In the above diagram, peers are ordered by their name (A, B, C, D). Connections to peers with a names later in the alphabet are in blue, connections to peers earlier in the alphabet are in red.

If you can order the peers somehow, only connecting to peers before oneself in the order (in red), and accepting connections from peers after oneself (again, red), will ensure you have only one connection per unique pair of peers.

Let's say you have `N` peers, and you order them somehow from `0` to `N-1`, inclusive.  Then, peer `i` needs to `accept()` connections from `N-1-i` peers, and `connect()` to `i` peers.

Of course, nothing is that simple in practice. The problem is that the peers may come up at different times, rather than simultaneously; and a connection will fail if the other end does not already have a listening socket corresponding to the address and port.  So, it is most important to make the listening socket first, ensure the backlog is large enough, and then make the connections.

If we look at [GIO GSocket](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSocket.html)s (since that seems to be what OP is using), the solution is rather simple, assuming all peers agree on their ordering.

1. All peers create a listening socket using `g_socket_new()`, `g_socket_bind()`, `g_set_backlog()`, and `g_socket_listen()`. The backlog should be at least the number of peers (less one).

   If new peers can be "invited in" at run time, use a larger backlog. If new peers cannot be invited in, then the last peer in the order does not need a listening socket, because it will only be making connections, not accepting incoming ones.
2. `i`th peer (first peer in order being `0`) creates `i` sockets to connect to peers before it in the ordering, using `g_socket_new()`, optionally `g_socket_bind()`, optionally `g_socket_set_blocking()` to make the connections nonblocking, and `g_socket_connect()`.

   If the socket was made nonblocking using `g_socket_set_blocking()`, then the peer can loop in `g_socket_check_connect_result()` or `g_socket_condition_check()`, to wait for all connections to complete.

   Note that because the real-world difference in when each peer creates its incoming socket, connections may fail (because the other end hasn't started yet). In those cases, you should simply retry; i.e. call `g_socket_connect()` again.

   (You can also use `g_socket_create_source()` to create a `GSource` from a socket, to treat it as an event source.)
3. At this point, the incoming connections should be backlogged in the OS networking stack (or will be), so peer `i` should use `g_socket_accept()` to accept incoming connections from the `N-1-i` peers after it in the ordering.

---

Personally, I would use a different architecture/approach, one that manages the peer list dynamically.

Let's say each peer has an unique identifier. (This could be e.g. the IPv6-mapped address and port, or the user nickname and their public key.)

When a connection is made, the connecting party sends an initial handshake, that contains its own identifier, and the identifier of the party it is trying to connect. When a new connection is accepted, the initial handshake is received (within some timeout interval). If the connecting party is a new one, it is added to the connected peers list. If it is already connected, either the new or the existing connection is dropped (after sending a packet that tells the reason for the drop).

This would also allow "invites", and sharing peer connection information across the mesh.

Comment: I decided to do what you personally would use. First because invitations are in my to-do-lists anyway and a different architecture clearly simplifies this already. I can order connections but I can't order accepts as the high level API will accept every inbound connection automatically and the connections will already be established. And as I mentioned I shall not use the lower-level `g_socket_` calls for I am using GSocketClient and GSocketService APIs.

Comment: Thanks for your quality educational answer. There is no much info on the subject elsewhere so I think it's golden.